# How do I prompt for input in a shell script?

Tags: shell, menu, sh

Trying to create a script which will install some packages on a router and at some point will ask user to input desired swap size. It's all OK, but at point 4 the script will exit and I want do not return to menu after selecting 1, 2 or 3 and to stay opened and continue running last part of code if I choose 4.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Some lines with code here...
# Swap file
while :
do
    clear
    echo Router model       
    cat "/proc/sys/kernel/hostname"
    echo "-----------"
    echo " SWAP FILE"
    echo "-----------"
    echo "Choose swap file size"
    echo "1. 256MB"
    echo "2. 512MB (recommended)"
    echo "3. 1024MB"
    echo "4. Skip, I already have a swap partition"
    echo "   or I don't want to create it right now"
        # get input from the user 
    read -p "Enter your choice [ 1 - 4 ] " choice
        # make decision using case..in..esac 
    case $choice in
        1)

            echo -e "$INFO Creating a 256MB swap file..."
            echo -e "$INFO This could take a while, be patient..."
            dd if=/dev/zero of=/opt/swap bs=1024 count=256144
            mkswap /opt/swap
            chmod 0600 /opt/swap
            read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..." readEnterKey
            ;;
        2) 
            echo -e "$INFO Creating a 512MB swap file..."
            echo -e "$INFO This could take a while, be patient..."
            dd if=/dev/zero of=/opt/swap bs=1024 count=524288
            mkswap /opt/swap
            chmod 0600 /opt/swap            
            read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..." readEnterKey
            ;;
        3)
            echo -e "$INFO Creating a 1024MB swap file..."
            echo -e "$INFO This could take a while, be patient..."
            dd if=/dev/zero of=/opt/swap bs=1024 count=1048576
            mkswap /opt/swap
            chmod 0600 /opt/swap
            read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..." readEnterKey
            ;;
        4)
            exit 1
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Error: Invalid option..." 
            read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..." readEnterKey
            ;;
    esac    
done

# Here will be the rest of the script
```

Comment: Where should I put "break" because if I put it after read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..." readEnterKey will exit and not executing the rest of the script

Comment: Look into using `select` for menus like this. It is what it was designed for.

Comment: @GigiDuru Cases 1-3 are virtually the same. Shouldn't they just set a couple of variables, and then those commands could be executed *after* the while loop *if* those variables are set?

Comment: Change your shebang to `#!/bin/bash`; you're using a lot of `bash` extensions that aren't guaranteed to work in an arbitrary POSIX shell.

Comment: Actually, break is the best method so far, this is my working script

Answer (score 0):

replace `exit 1` with `break`:

Something like this:

```
    1)
        echo -e "Some conditions"
        ;;
    2)
        break
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Error: Invalid option..."
        read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..." readEnterKey
        ;;
```

I'm not exactly sure if you're asking something different, but this will let you type option 1 multiple times, 2 only once, or "something else" (then enter) multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, break is the best method so far, this is my working script

```
# Swap file
while :
do
    clear
    echo Router model   
    cat "/proc/sys/kernel/hostname"
    echo "---------"
    echo "SWAP FILE"
    echo "---------"
    echo "Choose swap file size (Highly Recommended)"
    echo "1. 256MB"
    echo "2. 512MB (recommended)"
    echo "3. 1024MB"
    echo "4. Skip this step, I already have a swap file / partition"
    echo "   or I don't want to create one right now"
    read -p "Enter your choice [ 1 - 4 ] " choice
    case $choice in
        1)
            echo -e "$INFO Creating a 256MB swap file..."
            echo -e "$INFO This could take a while, be patient..."
            dd if=/dev/zero of=/opt/swap bs=1024 count=256144
            mkswap /opt/swap
            chmod 0600 /opt/swap
            swapon /opt/swap
            read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..." readEnterKey
            break
            ;;
        2) 
            echo -e "$INFO Creating a 512MB swap file..."
            echo -e "$INFO This could take a while, be patient..."
            dd if=/dev/zero of=/opt/swap bs=1024 count=524288
            mkswap /opt/swap
            chmod 0600 /opt/swap
            swapon /opt/swap
            read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..." readEnterKey
            break
            ;;
        3)
            echo -e "$INFO Creating a 1024MB swap file..."
            echo -e "$INFO This could take a while, be patient..."
            dd if=/dev/zero of=/opt/swap bs=1024 count=1048576
            mkswap /opt/swap
            chmod 0600 /opt/swap
            swapon /opt/swap
            read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..." readEnterKey
            break
            ;;
        4)
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "ERROR: INVALID OPTION!"
            echo "Press 1 to create a 256MB swap file"
            echo "Press 2 to create a 512MB swap file (recommended)"
            echo "Press 3 to create a 1024MB swap file"
            echo "Press 4 to skip swap creation (not recommended)" 
            read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..." readEnterKey
            ;;
    esac    
done
```

Can I simplify a little bit?

Comment: Can I simplify without repeating 3 times "echo -e "$INFO Creating a..."?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the read command.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Choose your option: "
read answser
# The value is now stored in the variable answer
# To check this, you can use an echo command
echo $answer
```

I hope I helped!

**EDIT**

It seems like i misunderstood your question.

Since I do want to help you, here is my correction. If you want to exit an entire script, you would use *exit*, like you did. If you only want to exit a certain loop/construction, you can use *break*. This would be applicable on your case.

An alternative solution is to just **leave out** the case option for the input 4!
It would look a little bit like this:

```
input=4
case $input in
  1) some stuff
  2) some stuff
  3) some stuff
esac
echo "Notice that I did not define any action for the value 4!"
```

Comment: Excuse my lack of proper understanding. I was in the process of editing my solution when you commented this. My apologies. I hope the second part of my answer does come in handy!

Comment: Sorry, none of this working for me, let me explain better:
This is not entire script just a piece in the middle, what I want is to show menu with available option: 1, 2, 3 or to skip execution when I choose 4 but after execute 1,2 or 3 do not show the menu again and execute the rest of the script, if I choose 4, I want to exit the loop and execute the rest of the script.